# How to create a custom socket event when using Formbuilder as GUI designer

Tags: c++, sockets, events, wxwidgets

I am trying to create a TCPsocket app with Code:Blocks 20.03, wxWidgets 3.15, and mingw64 on Windows 10.  with Formbuilder 3.10.1 as the GUI designer
I have studied and built the socket sample with success.
Now I would like to create a TCPsocket server in the app I am currently trying to create.
This is my first attempt to use sockets, and my first attempt to create a custom event.
The Server class is a Subclass of SocketTCPserver, which is generated by wxFormBuilder in the main GUI header and source file.

Because I used Formbuilder to create my GUI, I cannot use an Event Table.
So, I searched for a solution and found the one below creating the least amount of errors.
I am not sure what causes the warning: "EVT_SOCKET" redefined, and the error: 'EVT_SOCKET' was not declared in this scope.

I hope someone can help me understand and advise on how to create custom events in my situation.

below is the code I used:

```
#include "Server.h"

enum
{
    // id for sockets
    SERVER_ID = 100,
    SOCKET_ID
};

#define EVT_SOCKET(SOCKET_ID, OnSocketEvent) \
    wxDECLARE_EVENT(EVT_SOCKET, wxSocketEvent);

Server::Server( wxWindow* parent ) : SocketTCPserver( parent )
{
    Bind(EVT_SOCKET, &Server::OnSocketEvent, this);
}
```

I received the messages below from building:

```
||=== Build: Debug in ClientServer (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Socket\Client+Server\Server.cpp|22|warning: "EVT_SOCKET" redefined|
F:\SDKs\wx315\include\wx\socket.h|439|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Socket\Client+Server\Server.cpp||In constructor 'Server::Server(wxWindow*)':|
F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Socket\Client+Server\Server.cpp|28|error: 'EVT_SOCKET' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: What is the purpose of "#define EVT_SOCKET(SOCKET_ID, OnSocketEvent) "? check https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_socket_base.html

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't redefine `EVT_SOCKET` already defined by wxWidgets. Moreover, the type of the event you want to handle, and so should use with `Bind()`, is `wxEVT_SOCKET`.

Finally, I'd recommend using a dedicated library for any non-trivial network code rather than using `wxSocket` at all.

Comment: As said, I am a beginner on working with events.  When I use Bind(wxEVT_SOCKET(SERVER_ID), Server, Server::OnServerEvent);, I receive 2 errors. error: no match for call to '(const wxEventTypeTag<wxSocketEvent>) (<unnamed enum>)'| and error: expected primary-expression before ',' token|. Can you please show me the correct bind example for wxEVT_SOCKET?

Answer (score 0):

After many searches with google, I got it working.

I removed:

```
#define EVT_SOCKET(SOCKET_ID, OnSocketEvent) \
    wxDECLARE_EVENT(EVT_SOCKET, wxSocketEvent);
```

Instead of an event table, I tried Bind() to no avail.
Then I found a really good explanation for Connect().

Below 2 command work:

```
Connect(SERVER_ID, wxEVT_SOCKET, wxSocketEventHandler(Server::OnServerEvent));
Connect(SOCKET_ID, wxEVT_SOCKET, wxSocketEventHandler(Server::OnSocketEvent));
```

I now have a working server. The client should now be no problem.

I love learning :-)

Comment: `Connect` and `Bind` are "kind of" equivalent; however, I definitely suggest using `Bind` since it gives considerably more flexibilities.

Comment: @Ruud, with Bind() you have to use &Server::OnServerEvent. See the difference?